# STR_TO_DATE function returns 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql, date

I have a few columns of the varchar type with dates of different formats. I'm trying to change their format using the `STR_TO_DATE()` function and then change their type to date. I ran this query since the dates in this column were mm/dd/yyyy.

```
UPDATE `table` SET `date` = STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y');
```

However, it changed all the entries to `0000-00-00` and I have over `2000 rows` in this table. I'm trying to figure out why it did that before I apply it to the other rows. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What value(s) does `date` have before the update?

Comment: @Mureinik Just regular dates as strings eg. 5/27/2016

Comment: take a look to `DATE_FORMAT` function

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('5/27/2016', '%m/%d/%Y'); -- Result: 2016-05-27`

Comment: If the date time value passed into this function "STR_TO_DATE"  as string is illegal, the function returns NULL. So in the above scenario your string may be not valid. Take a look at that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I will double check everything again to make sure I didn't miss anything.

Comment: This might be to do with locale settings in your SQL client. MySQL stores them in the ISO date format: YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Do you have any sample data? That would help clarify your question considerably.

Answer (score -1):

> MySQL recognizes [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in either `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `'YY-MM-DD'` format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted: Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts. For example, `'2012-12-31'`, `'2012/12/31'`, `'2012^12^31'`, and `'2012@12@31'` are equivalent.
> - As a string with no delimiters in either `'YYYYMMDD'` or `'YYMMDD'` format, provided that the string makes sense as a date. For example, `'20070523'` and `'070523'` are interpreted as `'2007-05-23'`, but `'071332'` is illegal (it has nonsensical month and day parts) and becomes `'0000-00-00'`.
> - As a number in either `YYYYMMDD` or `YYMMDD` format, provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example, `19830905` and `830905` are interpreted as `'1983-09-05'`.

**Note:**

In your case

`UPDATE`table`SET`date`= STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y');`

The given date format while storing in database is not valid (that's why you got `0000-00-00`) . Because the date has already been stored in this format `'%Y-%m-%d'`.

However, if you want to display the stored date in your desired format (suppose your desired format is `'%m/%d/%Y'`) then you can use the following query:

`SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%m/%d/%Y')
FROM datetable;`

**More:**

Your update operation would work only if the following two conditions are met:

- Assuming valid dates are stored in your table (valid date format already stated above)
- And if you would use the following query instead the aforementioned query:

  `UPDATE datetable SET`date`= STR_TO_DATE(`date`,'%Y-%m-%d');` (in this case no row will be affected since you are trying to update with the same value)

Comment: Please tell me the reason behind downvoting. I can modify my answer then so that it conforms to the requirement.

Comment: It's "string to date" not "date to string". I think you're reading it backwards.

Comment: All I wanted to say that one cannot store/update date values in database unless the formatted date / date is MySQL supported ones. But one can adopt any valid date formats while displaying. @tadman

Comment: I hear you, but I still think this answer is a bit confused. The original question is rather strange, but I believe they may be trying to rescue data with date values stored in the wrong order.

Comment: But how can anybody store a date in wrong order? Because in MySQL while storing dates in wrong order the dates will be stored like `0000-00-00`. I don't know if I missed the subtle part of the question @tadman

Comment: Some dates like `01-02-03` are ambiguous. I don't know "how", people find "ways".

Comment: Maybe date like `01-02-03` is treated a date under current century. But a date like `83-02-03` is treated as 19th century's date. @tadman